# Cycles: realistic light refraction for glass lenses

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, glass, photorealism

I found this image somewhere on the Internet:

[image: Source]

It was made with Cinema 4D and some special renderer. I decided to try create somethings similar using our favourite Blender and Cycles.

To achieve a nice rainbow refraction I created the following nodes setup for lens  material glass:

[image: Color refraction nodes]

And here are my render settings and my best result (with sampling = 48):

[image: Sampling 48]

I tried to set more sampling (256), but the result doesn't seem to be better, just more noise light:

[image: Sampling 256]

In addition, I tried to use volume scatter in the world nodes, but this gives only noise in the all scene, even no light is seen through the lens:

[image: Stupid world volume scatter]

---

Also, my mirror made with simple glossy shader doesn't seem to work nicely too as it can be observed from pictures above – it doesn't reflect light to the left side of the image. It just reflects the scene:

[image: Simple mirror]

Here there are it's material nodes:

[image: Stupid mirror]

The lens was made from subdivided ico sphere, and the lens, the light, and the mirror (made with a cube) have the same Z coordinate.

---

So, is it possible to achieve more realism close to the first picture? And how?

Comment: Friendly advice. Don't bother with such effects in Cycles. It's not spectral renderer and it's not using photon mapping. It's not right tool for such use. Try to search about Cycles caustics. There are many (many) topics about it.

Comment: @cgslav thank you! Indeed, I though that Cycles is created for super-realism, but it turns out that it has some limitations too. And it seems that many people don't understand this limitations (just like me several minutes ago). Because I've seen many similar questions without a good explanation. However, I'll appreciate any answer that will make my scene more similar to the first picture – yes, with fake approaches.